# Add button and title on submenu WordPress

Tags: wordpress, filter, menu

I would like to add a "Back" button and menu title on the submenu but I do not know how. I am guessing to use `wp_nav_menu_items()` filter but I am not 100% sure how to start.

Here's what I would like to achieve:
[image]

I hope the photo is understandable. Basically I have this primary menu wherein the **Resources** has a dropdown menu. Now I want to add a back button and the menu title on the submenu (dropdown).

I hope I am making sense. Thank you!

Comment: Is this a custom theme build? What are you using to output your menu? I would usually build menus from scratch using get_pages() or get_posts() so I have more control over them. Filters can be a little bit limited when you want to customise so I tend to rarely use wp_nav_menu()

Comment: Hey @Paul, I use `wp_nav_menu()`. What do you think? I am not sure how to implement it. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: I think if you were to build the menu yourself instead of using get_pages() you'd have much more control over how you customise it but you do need to do a little more work when building dropdowns etc.